# How can I use GOOGLEFINANCE to return a share price in a certain currency?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-finance

I have shares in different currencies that I want to track in only a single currency. I currently have a cell that returns the currency and one that returns the price, I then multiply them. However, I'm trying to make the sheet fully automated so I was wondering if it is possible to have something like

```
=googlefinance("RIO","price","CAD")?
```

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 2):

Welcome, Eric! Google Finance tracks exchange rates. The syntax is:
`=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:BRLCAD")`
where BRLCAD is the two currencies, in this case Brazilian Real to Canadian Dollar, in [ISO 4217 format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217#Active_codes).

Use that as your multiplier to convert from source shares to their value in the new currency. For example, if your price is in A2,
`= A2 * GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:BRLCAD")`

Comment: Additionally you can use `=googlefinance("RIO", "currency")` to know on what currency is traded the share of your interess.